# code not running in console! Way to simplify and make it run?

Tags: c++, c++14, game-development, replit

I am making a program that outputs each char green, yellow, or red depending on whether it matches the word. I have tried making a function that takes In the user guess and compares it against the word. I have just given values to each to test it. When I click run nothing happens it just sits there in replit and VS Code.

first if: checks if the word is equal and if it is returns the entire word.

If the entire world is not equal then I try going through each char.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
#include <random>
using namespace std;

string fun2(string user_guess, string word)
{
    int num = 1; //num for loop
    int num1 = 0; // for yellow to stay const
    int num2 = 0; // postion of char
    bool a1 = false;

    if (user_guess == word) {
        cout << "\033[30;42m" << user_guess << "\033[0m\n"; //returns entire word in green
    }
    else {
        while (num <= word.length()) { //Goes through each char in the word
            if (user_guess[num2] == word[num2]) {
                cout << "\033[30;42m" << user_guess[num2] << "\033[0m\n"; // return char in green
                num2++;
                num++;
                num1++;
            }
            else {
                while (num2 <= word.length()) { // checcks wether char is equal to any other char in the word
                    if (user_guess[num] == word[num2]) {
                        a1 = true;
                    }
                }
                if (a1 == true) {
                    cout << "\033[30;103m" << user_guess[num] << "\033[0m\n"; // return yellow
                }
                else {
                    cout << "\033[30;41m" << user_guess[num2] << "\033[0m\n"; // return red
                }
                num2++;
                num++;
                num1++;
            }
        }
    }
    return "Thanks";
}

int main()
{
    string word = "cake";
    string user_guess = "fake";
    cout << fun2(user_guess, word);
}
```

Comment: `while(num <= word.length())` looks like undefined behavior. The valid indices into `word` are `0` to `word.length() - 1`, _not_ including `word.length()`. C++ indexing starts at `0`.

Comment: what is the use of `num1`, take a good look at `a1` use

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are doing, you are making things quite a bit harder of yourself than they need to be. You are already using `std::string`. To find if the current character in `user_guess` appears elsewhere in `word`, you can simply use the [std::basic_string::find_first_of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of) member function by searching `word` from the current index for a character that matches the current character in `user_guess`.

For example, you can simply do:

```cpp
std::string fun2 (std::string user_guess, std::string word)
{
    if (user_guess == word) {   /* words are equal, all green */
        std::cout << "\033[30;42m" << user_guess << "\033[0m\n";
        return "Success";
    }
    
    /* loop over each char (up to shorter of either string) */
    for (int i = 0; user_guess[i] && word[i]; i++) {
        if (user_guess[i] == word[i]) {   /* chars match, green */
            std::cout << "\033[30;42m" << user_guess[i] << "\033[0m";
        }
        /* current char found elsewhere in word - yellow */
        else if (word.find_first_of (user_guess[i], i) != std::string::npos) {
            std::cout << "\033[30;103m" << user_guess[i] << "\033[0m";
        }
        else {  /* current char does not exist in word - red */
            std::cout << "\033[30;41m" << user_guess[i] << "\033[0m";
        }
    }
    
    return "\nThanks";
}
```

(**note:** there is no need for an `else` after `user_guess` and `word` match, you are simply done at that point. Simply return from inside that block rather than using an `else` and forcing an additional level of indentation for the remainder of the code in the `else` block)

To match the current character in `user_guess` to any character in `word` starting from the beginning of `word` instead of the current index, you can use `word.find_first_of (user_guess[i], 0)`.

The line `using namespace std;` was removed. See [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/364696)

Hardcoding strings makes it impossible to change `word` or `user_guess` without recompiling your code. You shouldn't have to recompile your code to simply provide a different `word` or `user_guess`, that's what the parameters to `main()`, e.g. `int argc, char **argv`, are for.

Simply pass `word` and `user_guess` as the first two arguments on the command line (or prompt the user for input and read from `stdin`). Taking the arguments as the first two command line parameters, you could do:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
...
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc < 3) {
        std::cerr << "usage:  ./prog word user_guess.\n";
        return 1;
    }
    
    std::string word { argv[1] };
    std::string user_guess { argv[2] };
    
    std::cout << fun2(user_guess, word) << '\n';
}
```

(**note:** those are the only two headers required by your code. Avoid including superfluous header files)

**Example Use/Output**

If I understood your goal, using:

```
$ ./bin/word_game_color cake fake
fake
Thanks
```

Where `fake` is `red,green,green,green`.

If we change it to: `./bin/word_game_color cake feke` then the output of `feke` is `red,yellow,green,green`.

In case of a match, you have, e.g.

```
$ ./bin/word_game_color cake cake
cake
Success
```

Where `cake` is output all green.

---

**Handling `user_guess` Longer Than `word`**

You likely want to handle cases where `user_guess` and `word` are of differing length. In that case simply add an additional loop to loop over any remaining characters in `user_guess` while searching for the matching character anywhere in `word` from the beginning.

You can do that with:

```cpp
std::string fun2 (std::string user_guess, std::string word)
{
    int i = 0;
    
    if (user_guess == word) {   /* words are equal, all green */
        std::cout << "\033[30;42m" << user_guess << "\033[0m\n";
        return "Success";
    }
    
    /* loop over each char (up to shorted of either string) */
    for (; user_guess[i] && word[i]; i++) {
        if (user_guess[i] == word[i]) {   /* chars match, green */
            std::cout << "\033[30;42m" << user_guess[i] << "\033[0m";
        }
        /* current char found elsewhere in word - yellow */
        else if (word.find_first_of (user_guess[i], 0) != std::string::npos) {
            std::cout << "\033[30;103m" << user_guess[i] << "\033[0m";
        }
        else {  /* current char does not exist in word - red */
            std::cout << "\033[30;41m" << user_guess[i] << "\033[0m";
        }
    }
    
    /* user_guess longer than word -- loop remaining chars */
    for (; user_guess[i]; i++) {
        /* current char found elsewhere in word - yellow */
        if (word.find_first_of (user_guess[i], 0) != std::string::npos) {
            std::cout << "\033[30;103m" << user_guess[i] << "\033[0m";
        }
        else {  /* current char does not exist in word - red */
            std::cout << "\033[30;41m" << user_guess[i] << "\033[0m";
        }
    }
    
    return "\nThanks";
}
```

In that case if you used `"cake"` for `word` and `"cakebake"` for `user_guess` you would have:

```
$ ./bin/word_game_color cake cakebake
cakebake
Thanks
```

Where `cakebake` is `green,green,green,green,red,yellow,yellow,yellow`.

Let me know if I misunderstood what your goal was. This made sense given what you had so far -- but greatly simplified things.

Comment: I was at school I was not able to respond quickly. This code I had actually copied and pasted into a separate .cpp file so I can fix the problems that were occurring. So I gave word and user_guess predefined values so I can test it. What I was trying to do is have a word and compare that against the userr_guess. Depending on if word[0] and user_guess[0] match return the letter in green, and if they don't match return red, if user_guess[0] matches with any other letter in a word other than the same position of char it's being compared to.

Comment: I just did not know how to approach the part comparing the word[pos_char] with every other letter in the word. I have only been coding in c++ for like 2 or 3 months, do you recommend any books, sites, or resources I could use to learn and pick up new things. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes, that makes much more sense. The code above shows exactly how to implement the coloring of characters and the `user_guess` and `word` and basically test-cases for that above. To change the code to have the `word` provided on the command line and then the `user_guess` prompted for is a small change. It's just a matter of getting the input from a different source (for you `word` you could also simply pick a random number from a dictionary file). Do you want to take a stab at modifying the code or do you need help figuring out where to start there? I don't mind helping further.

Comment: As for a book, see [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/3422102). There is no replacement for coding, trial/error, using the book and [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/) as your reference. Asking questions here (after your good-faith attempt to solve a problem and with your well formatted and specific questions) is invaluable. Nothing like being able to get a glimpse of how others with experience approach different problems. (asking "I wonder if I can make the code do X?" -- and then doing it, is the best learning of all) It takes time.

Comment: I will take a try first and try putting it all together today and tomorrow. If I have questions I will definitely ask. Thanks for the help

Comment: Drop a comment here and I'll get it. I would ask the question "Can I create a file named dictionary.txt with `bake, cake, fake, lake, make, cat, dog, frog`, etc.. one on each line. Generate a random number between `1-8` (the number of words in dictionary.txt) and loop that many times reading/dicarding each word until you reach your random line number and read `word`. Now prompt the user for input and read `user_guess`?". Get it working for one `word` and `guess` and then put it in a loop so the user can play any number of times, simply hitting [Enter] on an empty line to quit. (good learning)